# Bulk delete with checkboxes and additional values

Tags: html, checkbox, asp-classic

So I think I'm in some kind of tunnel-vision right now.

I have to maintain a very basic application (HTML + ASP). In this application, there is a small table with some values:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Customer-ID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Waregroup</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some other ID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[edit]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[delete]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[checkbox for deletion]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It looks like this, to make it more visual (excluded the rows with data, they are not needed for this):

[image]

Now, the `delete`-function just doesn't take simply the customer-id (KD Nr.), it takes several more arguments, which are provided in a link. For example, this here:

```
someSite.com?sid=123456&gkid=133&kdid=9043168&wws=9&del=1
```

Some of the values are taken from the QueryString, other from a ResultSet from a SQL-Query.

Now I had to extend this application and add a checkbox to bulk-deletion. This wasn't a problem at all, but now I'm kinda stuck on how to get the values which are required for the deletion, when I can basically just use 1 value in each checkbox. I thought about using hidden inputs, but then I have no idea how to determine, which "rows" should be deleted and which not:

This is the addtion I made:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="deletebox[]" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<%=Request.QueryString("sid")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="gkid" value="<%=Request.QueryString("gkid")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="kdid" value="<%=rs("ka_kdnr")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="wws" value="<%=rs("ka_sysid")%>">
</td>
```

My idea is to loop through every checked checkbox, take the values from the hidden fields and run my deletion-script in a loop.

Any lead on how to do so? Can I simply iterate over all checked checkboxes and `request` for the current value of the hidden fields?

I basically just need the **gkid** and the **gkkid** for the stored procedure to work.

Comment: Do you have to use the existing single item delete methods? I would build a collection of IDs to delete and pass that to the app for deletion.

Comment: Instead of looping through the form to find checked boxes, you should call a jquery function that triggers onclick then passes the parameters for that row to page that will do the deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit a form which contains multiple instances of the same form variable then that the value of that variable in the Request object will appear as a comma separated array.  In other words if your form contains the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gkid" value="25">
<input type="checkbox" name="gkid" value="50">
<input type="checkbox" name="gkid" value="75">
```

Then `Request("gkid")` will display a value of "25,50,75" if you check all of them. You can then split your array as follows.

```
For i = 1 to Request("gkid").Count
     Response.write Request("gkid")(i) & "<br>" & vbcrlf
Next
```

I'm going to assume that you can take it from there and adapt the above to use `Request.Form("gkid")(i)` and apply logic inside the loop with code which calls your stored procedure.

Your question mentions a variable called "gkkid".  I can't see where that comes from.  If I could I might be able to improve on this answer.

Comment: No need to improve :) That comma-separated list was the clue i was missing. Thanks for that :)